# There is a large delay before bolt(split) start processing when spout emits data in word-count using storm

Tags: apache-storm, word-count, stream-processing

We have set up a cluster running Apache Storm and tested word count. There are three components: spout, split and count. Since word count is very simple and I suppose that readers should understand the components and the topology.

Here is the problem. Split has four executors and so does count. After submitting the topology, the first time when spout begins emitting messages to split, there is a large delay (about 1 minute or even 2 minutes) before split begin processing data from spout. If we restart the worker where split executors reside, it also takes tens of seconds for newly-started split executor to start processing data.

I wonder if this is normal for storm? Since our experiment aims at rescheduling the assignment of executors in workers to improve performance, such a large delay will result in low performance, violating our goals.

We add log into spout and bolts so that when the first time it start to process will be logged. We find that split immediately started to work after spout, while count wait for a long time to start. All of the executors reside in the same worker. We tested many times and the result is similar.

Log info is below:

> 2018-12-25 19:45:26.693 STDIO Thread-26-spout-executor[13 13] [INFO] Spout start to process.
>   2018-12-25 19:45:26.701 STDIO Thread-18-split-executor[9 9] [INFO] Split start >to process.
>   2018-12-25 19:45:26.703 STDIO Thread-30-split-executor[10 10] [INFO] Split start to process.
>   2018-12-25 19:45:26.747 STDIO Thread-20-split-executor[11 11] [INFO] Split start to process.
>   2018-12-25 19:45:26.748 STDIO Thread-6-split-executor[12 12] [INFO] Split start to process.
>   2018-12-25 19:47:16.366 STDIO Thread-10-count-executor[7 7] [INFO] Count start to process.
>   2018-12-25 19:47:16.367 STDIO Thread-4-count-executor[8 8] [INFO] Count start to process.
>   2018-12-25 19:47:16.368 STDIO Thread-28-count-executor[5 5] [INFO] Count start to process.
>   2018-12-25 19:47:16.369 STDIO Thread-16-count-executor[6 6] [INFO] Count start to process.

Comment: How are you measuring the delay? When I set up a local Storm cluster with the word count topology, it looks like it takes about 5 seconds for a splitter executor to start processing again if I kill it. I'm basing this on worker log timestamps.

Comment: Do you see something related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50436973/1610034), I have also seen worker taking lot of time when there is lot parallelism for executors.

Comment: @StigRohdeDøssing I observed from storm ui that split executor statistics remain 0 until a large delay later. Then small amount of messages are processed at first and finally everything seems fine. There are some failed messages at that time suggesting that split do delayed and affected Acks to spout even if they reside in the same worker.

Comment: @saurabh Our topology is very simple and start very quickly.

Comment: @stigrohdedøssing and the storm version we use is 1.1.1

Comment: There can be a pretty long delay for storm ui updates, especially when starting the topology. Looking at the log timestamps is a more reliable way to tell when the executors are running. Could you try looking in the worker logs for the workers running split? Regarding the failures, you should expect some messages to fail when you kill one of the workers.

Comment: @stigrohdedøssing Yes! We modified the code and output a log when they process the first tuple they got. The delay is indeed very short. Thank you! However, we don't understand why there is a short delay  in UI updates for spout, but a long delay for spli. Maybe spout is handled specially. Anyway, we are glad our storm is working well. Thank you for your advice~

Comment: @stigrohdedøssing After experiments, we find that the problem is in count, not in split. It's count that delayed to process data even if all of them are in the same worker. I have updated the context above and paste the log text. Count delayed for two minutes to process data. Do you know why this would happen? Something wrong with our storm configuration?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Storm 1.2.2. It takes around 5 seconds from worker launch until the first tuple is processed by count for me. Please try upgrading to 1.2.2, so we're at least sure it's not a fixed bug.

Comment: Also I think you should post the command you use to launch the topology, as well as the storm.yaml you're using.

Comment: @stigrohdedøssing Thank you for your advice. We examined the code we use and find out that it is a segment in split that delayed count. The segment consumes CPU for less than 1 millisecond, but still it would result in a large delay in count. After deleting the segment, count starts immediately when spout begins emitting data.